# Request is going on pending upon sending email using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, api, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send email using nodejs. Here is my code

```
export function createOrder(req, res) {
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    secure: false,
    port: 25,
    auth: {
        user: 'fahadsubzwari924@gmail.com',
        pass: 'Jumpshare1'
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'Fahad <fahadsubzwari924@gmail.com>',
    to: 'shan4usmani@hotmail.com',
    subject: 'Order Status ',
    text: 'Your order has finished'
}
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, res) {
    if (res) {
        console.log(res);
        res.json({
            message: res,
            status: 200
        })
    } else {
        console.log(err, 'Error');
    }
  })
 }
```

When i am trying to send email then email is sending successfully but request is going on pending for a long time which is shown in network section of chrome. 
How can i get rid of this request pending issue?

Comment: Don't wait for nodemailer response, resolve your request before completion of sendMail method as sometimes it may take more time like 10 to 15 sec. Use async behaviour

Comment: thank you, I solved it by myself.

Comment: What approach you used ?

Comment: i removed promise and simply send email and in callback just check for the error first if error is not there so in else i am sending response. And it is working fine now